# Early 00s maybe late 90s show about a boy that was able to go into a video game and meet with a purple creature

Tags: story-identification, tv, isekai

I remember watching this show about a kid that was able to get into a video game through a secret portal behind it. Inside he would turn animated and had a purple dragon-ish looking friend. I also remember in one chapter the creature came out to the real world.

Comment: So, was this door in something like a videogame arcade? Was this live-action, cartoon, a mix of the two mediums?

Comment: Do you remember what network you watched this show on?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure this was ***[Zixx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zixx)*** (2004-2009).

> Zixx is an Intergalactic Network (simplified as the Network) agent who has crash-landed on Earth with her partner, Flanngo. As luck would have it, Earth also happens to be a hotbed of activity for the evil Onccalon and the Hargokk Empire. Zixx has no intention of letting him win, so she and Flanngo need to find a way to access the Network and make sure they can get to the next level of the Keep before Onccalon's henchmen do.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you describe the elements of this show that match the details of the question?